# Attempting to register while current state is RESUMED

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an app with webview, that have simple file picker html element:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
```

And to get it work, I build the below code, that is working well, opening the chooser intent and allow me to select either camera or file explorer to pick a ready picture.

i've an issue now to how to process the returned results, as the `startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST)` is deprecated.

I like having my code is small pieces of files, so I wrote the last 2 files to handle the results `CamResult` and `SelectorResult`, but got the error:

> Attempting to register while current state is RESUMED

I read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=fr#separate) but did not know how to implement it in my case!

MainActivity.kt:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Global.context = baseContext
        Global.activity = this

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        Global.webView = binding.webView
        WebListener.initiate()
        WebSettings.setUp()
    }
}
```

WebListener.Kt

```kotlin
interface WebListener {
    companion object {
        fun initiate() {
            Global.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                    view.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Welcome to native app')")
                }
            }

          Global.webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
              override fun onShowFileChooser(
                    webView: WebView,
                    filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>,
                    fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams
                ): Boolean {
                   Util.displayMessage("selected")
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            Global.context,
                            Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            Global.activity,
                            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                            0
                        )
                    }
                    FileChooser.create()
                    filePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null)
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FileChooser.kt

```kotlin
interface FileChooser {
    companion object {
        fun create() {
            val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(Global.activity.packageManager)?.also {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                try {
                    // photoFile = createImageFile()
                    Global.photoURI = ImageUri.create() //createImageUri()
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Global.photoURI)

                } catch (ex: Exception) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Util.displayMessage(ex.message.toString())
                }
            }

            val intentArray: Array<Intent?> = arrayOf(takePictureIntent)
            val contentSelectionIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
            contentSelectionIntent.let{
                it.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                          it.type = "image/*"
            }

          val chooserIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)

          chooserIntent.let {
              it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent)
              it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser")
              it.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray)
              Global.activity.startActivity(it)
          }
        }
    }
}
```

CamResult.kt

```kotlin
interface CamResult {
    companion object {
        val pickResult = Global.activity.registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) {
            Global.webView.loadUrl("javascript:showResponse()")
        }
    }
}
```

SelectorResult.kt

```kotlin
interface SelectorResult {
    companion object {
        val pickResult = Global.activity.registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) {
            Global.webView.loadUrl("javascript:showResponse()")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, by registering the responces at main activity, as:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        Global.context = baseContext
        Global.activity = this
        CameraResults.register()
   }
}
```

And the resonces are defined as:

```kotlin
interface CameraResults {
    companion object {
        fun register() {
            Global.CameraResult = Global.activity.registerForActivityResult(
                ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
            ) { result: ActivityResult ->
                    if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        result.data?.let {
                            val f = GetFileFromUrl.getFileFromUri(it.data!!)
                            Global.activity.contentResolver.query(it.data!!, null, null, null, null)
                            ?.use { cursor ->
                                val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                                val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
                                cursor.moveToFirst()
                              //  val n = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                              //  val s = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex).toString()
                              //  Util.displayMessage("$n / $s")
                            }

                            when (it.extras) {}
                        }
                        Global.webView.loadUrl("javascript:showResponse()")
                    } else {
                       // Util.displayMessage("Sorry no image camputred")
                    }
                }
      }
    }
}
```

My full code is [here](https://github.com/hajsf/go-android-photo/tree/main/main/java/tk/anative) if interested to have a look.